# Why isn't my hyperlink working in Javascript?

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink, scope, popup

I'm new to Javascript, and this hyperlink works fine for me in HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="auth.index.stores.store.campaign.design">Add artwork for the campaign</a>
```

However, the link doesn't show up as clickable when I render it like this in Javascript as a popup message:

```
let link = "auth.index.stores.store.campaign.design";
let uploadImage = "<a ui-sref='" + link + "'>upload an image</a>";
scope.error = {title: "Oops! You forgot something!", message: 'Please' + uploadImage + 'before launching your campaign.'};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Ended up using an error modal and passing in link in the body.

Comment: So ui-sref is a angular-directive and wont compile if you provide it as a string.

Comment: What kind of popup are you using?

Answer (score 1):

T Daddy.
This can help you, using angularjs. I hope I can help you.!!

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="vm.test()">TEST</button>
```

Module:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('auth.index.stores.store.campaign.design', {
        url: '/uploadImage',
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'menuContent':{
          templateUrl: 'templateUploadImage.html',
            controller: 'uploadImageController as vm'
          }
        }
    })
```

Controller:
Function that must be inside the controller defined in your module

```
 vm.test = function(){
    uploadImage();
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let link = $state.href('auth.index.stores.store.campaign.design', {}, { absolute: true, inherit: false });
let uploadImage = "<a ui-sref='" + link + "'>upload an image</a>";
scope.error = {title: "Oops! You forgot something!", message: 'Please' + uploadImage + 'before launching your campaign.'};
```